# need php executed in one directory only

Tags: php

What I want to do is add the php code below to the top of my site and have it run only for my /view/ directory, but I have no idea how to do this. So it needs to run on  www.mysite.com/view/page1.html and .../view/page2.html and so on for all the thousands of pages in this directory. What happens when I add this code now is that it does the intended job for the /view/ pages, but it gives an error on all the other pages on my site.

Here is the code which I'm trying to modify to only execute for those pages:

```
<!--[Include Template code/img.tpl]-->
<!--[Array $en SELECT i_id, i_name FROM $picstable WHERE i_user=$en[mm_id] AND i_status=2]-->
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I get worried when I see PHP code not using [PHP Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) to prevent [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) vulnerabilities. I hope you are sanitizing your variables in code that hasn't been pasted here. If not, please consider re-writing the code to use PDO Prepared Statements rather than trying to sanitize your variables.

Comment: it gives an error on all the other pages on my site, 
What's the error??

Comment: @AndyGee it just brings a blank page.

Comment: Maybe you could post some code that should produce an output. Maybe what you do with $en['m'.$key] after you've changed the new lines to <br /> tags

Comment: @sarnold I edited the code, is it better now?

Comment: I was hoping to be able to use an if command so something like if directory = view then echo this code? I'm sorry this is my first day dealing with php I have no idea how to do this :(

Comment: @Jodian: I think your previous version more clearly showed what you're doing; but I an much more worried about the security of your site. I hope you are sanitizing the variables that you are using in your SQL queries -- if you aren't, please take your code offline, and read about SQL Injection vulnerabilities...

Answer (score 0):

You can read the path with getcwd() in your current script.

Then you parse it and cheak if last dir in path is view, then add this code, otherwise just skip adding it.